# Storing Directory Paths Efficiently in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

I'm looking for a way to store directory paths in Java without using a large amount of memory. In my current program I have a Hashmap of which stores the full path to each file as a key along with their value.

```
private HashMap<String, Double> fileStorage = new HashMap<>();
```

This method will repeat the path when there are multiple files within a single folder e.g. Two files in the same folder will be stored as

```
/var/www/example.com/html/index.php
/var/www/example.com/html/style.css
```

The path to the files is repeated and is a waste of memory. What would you recommend I do in order to reduce the impact on memory?

Remember there can also be files 1 directory away e.g

```
/var/www/example.com/html/js/jquery.js
or
/var/www/example.com/example.mp3
```

Comment: My recommendation would pretty much be to build a directory structure yourself -- a folder with a list of internal folders and files, etc.

Comment: @LouisWasserman do you mean a Map of folders containing files and Maps of internal folders containing ... etc? Or do you literally mean build a directory?

Comment: I wouldn't even use maps at the top level, I'd build `class Directory { private Set<String> files; private Map<String, Directory> subdirectories; }` and the like.

Comment: Im assuming he meant some sort of object that represents a folder that can have other folder objects and file names inside it?

Comment: Just curious, how many path entries do you store?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UUID approach for that, using for the key map something like this

```
UUID uid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("/var/www/example.com/html/index.php".getBytes());
```

When you need get a value from Map pass the path string to UUID before the map `get` operation

You can create a method for generate a long (numeric) value from the UUID to optimize more the memory usage